# How to debug variables in the Observatory's debugger console?

Tags: debugging, flutter

When putting a `debugger;` statement in my code and opening the isolate in the Observatory vm, I can see the code being stopped at the breakpoint's frame, and the variables shown next to the frame, as well as a shell to execute command lines.

I'd like to play with the variables, see what methods do objects hold, test operations in the observatory before writing the code, but variables are unavailable from the command line.

[image]

here is the help text:

```
$ h
List of commands:

break        - Add a breakpoint by source location or function name (hotkey: [F8])
clear        - Remove a breakpoint by source location or function name (hotkey: [F8])
cls          - Clear the console
continue, c  - Resume execution of the isolate (hotkey: [F7])
delete       - Remove a breakpoint by breakpoint id
down         - Move down one or more frames (hotkey: [Page Down])
finish       - Continue running the isolate until the current function exits
frame, f     - Set the current frame
help         - List commands or provide details about a specific command
info         - Show information on a variety of topics
isolate, i   - Switch, list, rename, or reload isolates
log          - Control which log messages are displayed
next, n      - Continue running the isolate until it reaches the next source location in the current function (hotkey: [F9])
next-async   - Step over await or yield
next-sync    - Run until return/unwind to current activation.
pause        - Pause the isolate (hotkey: [Ctrl ;])
print, p     - Evaluate and print an expression in the current frame
refresh      - Refresh debugging information of various sorts
reload       - Reload the sources for the current isolate
rewind       - Rewind the stack to a previous frame
set          - Set a debugger option
step, s      - Continue running the isolate until it reaches the next source location (hotkey: [F10]
up           - Move up one or more frames (hotkey: [Page Up])
vm           - Manage a Dart virtual machine

For more information on a specific command type 'help <command>'
For a list of hotkeys type 'help hotkeys'

Command prefixes are accepted (e.g. 'h' for 'help')
Hit [TAB] to complete a command (try 'is[TAB][TAB]')
Hit [ENTER] to repeat the last command
Use up/down arrow for command history
```

It looks like there is no way to enter the function and execute dart commands. Did I miss something ? How would I go about investigating objects and their methods ?

In this example, I wanted to investigate the DatabaseReference object `reference` from FirebaseDatabase, to figure out how to remove an existing entry. Not sure how to get this done without access to an interpreter.

Maybe I'm surprised as coming from Python, which debugger includes an interpreter ? But this doesn't sound impossible to do in Dart, with tools like DartPad or projects like [dart-console](https://github.com/sam-mccall/dart-console)

Comment: Figured out howo to remove an entry by searching the [online documentation](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/firebase_database/0.1.2/firebase_database/DatabaseReference-class.html), but it's a lot more time consuming than printing variable methods from a breakpoint shell.
Now struggling on how to search the reference's list of object by object key.

Comment: Well, at least that forced me to dig in the doc/code and figure it out by myself, good learning experience.

Comment: Could you write up your findings as an answer? I am interested in this too